# How to implement lazy loading feature using ReactJS (append child doesn't work with React)?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS and I have a simple list of items made using `ul li`. I'm trying to implement lazy loading feature here, however I'm stuck with the fact that React doesn't provide any `append` method. So I'm not able to append the new set of items in the list to the existing ones once you scroll down. I don't want to re-render the whole list again with the new set of items included. Pls help.

Comment: React is all about re-rendering everything. This sounds like a waste but it works really well. The goal is to not have you think about whether you want to append. You have these list items, you have this scroll position, therefore you have this representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React will not "re-render" the DOM on each render call, it will calculate the differences in it’s virtual DOM and update accordingly.

So if you return more items from the render function based on a certain state (f.ex after scroll), React will automatically "append" the new items in the DOM.